# Percentage from a range of a given value

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I need a math formula (or direct JS code) to get the percentage from a range of a given value:

```
//For example:

Range 1: [-5, 5] ->  given value: 6 -> percentage will be 110%
                 ->  given value: 5 -> percentage will be 100%
                 ->  given value: -5-> percentage will be -100%
```

Comment: Assuming that 0 is 0%, 6 is 120%. the formula is `x * 20` in that case. Assuming that 6 *is* 110%, -5 is %0. In that case the formula is `(x * 10) + 50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the work:

```js
const getValueFromPercentage = function (range, percentage)
{
    var scope = range[1]-range[0];
    var result = ((scope / 100) * percentage) + range[0];
    return result;
}

console.log(getValueFromPercentage([0, 10 ], 5 ));
console.log(getValueFromPercentage([4, 20 ], 12));
console.log(getValueFromPercentage([0, 100], 100));
```